# WebApp that uses Dropbox for storage of videos and PDF

Tags: php, dropbox, dropbox-api

We're building a website that essentially allows you to record a video of you reading off a PDF that can be accessed by other people.

The kicker is that the client wants us to store (and access via the webapp) these videos and pdfs on the user's **personal** dropbox account.

Is this even possible? Honestly, this just went over my head and although DropBox's API documentation looks like it could be able to handle this functionality it doesn't sound like this is something that DropBox should be used for.

So here are my questions (apart from the initial, "is it possible?"):

*If* this is possible, aside from the individual storage limit, what other disadvantages would this setup have over getting and paying for an actual server?

Are there specific things I should be aware of that might be against DropBox's TOS? I've read the TOS and it doesn't look like this would be prohibited but we can't be too sure right?

PS. if it matters this is going to be built on Wordpress / PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This certainly sounds possible. For example, the Dropbox API offers calls for uploading, downloading, and sharing files:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files-GET
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files_put
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#shares

The basic idea would be to have user link their personal Dropbox account initially, and the server would store the access token on the backend, to make whatever API calls on behalf of that user as necessary. (Whether that is to initially upload the data, or to later retrieve it for use.)

One thing to be aware of, if you end up using the shared link feature, is the bandwidth limits:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/45/en